# How does Oracle handle accents in queries?

Tags: python, oracle

I'm using python to execute the following query in Oracle:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE DATA = 'CAMIÓN'
```

I'm getting a 0 when I should be getting a value different to 0 because there are rows where DATA is 'CAMIÓN'.

If you execute the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE DATA = 'CAMIN'
```

It will give you 0, so I'm thinking it might be due to the accent because it doesn't give an error, it seems oracle is removing the troubled character.

How does Oracle handle the accents? Does it remove those?

Answer (score 0):

If alternative convention spelling is enabled, then the acents equivalent word will be taken by oracle.

For Example,

Character  Alternative Spelling
ä           ae

You can use ctx_ddl.unset_attribute/ctx_ddl.set_attribute to set or unset alternative spelling conventions.

Comment: It's not my database so I don't have access to that.

Comment: The database uses: 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET -> AL16UTF16 
NLS_CHARACTERSET -> AL32UTF8

Comment: Its not like nls_characterset , its a preference. you can use data dictionary view to check preference - CTX_PREFERENCE_VALUES,CTX_PREFERENCES

Comment: I have no idea how to check that.